# Binning Raw Scores to a hundred BINs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have RAW_SCORE in a column in my data frame and would like to bin these values to 100 Bins and store this in a column called SCORE.
But my code is creating NaN values.

Here is my code:

```
bins = list(range(1, 101))
df_output['SCORE'] = pd.cut(df_output['RAW_SCORE'], bins)
```

Here is the output:

```
RAW_SCORE   SCORE
0.000742    NaN
0.000745    NaN
0.000826    NaN
0.000849    NaN
0.000853    NaN
0.000884    NaN
0.000911    NaN
0.00097     NaN
0.001014    NaN
0.001027    NaN
```

What I am expecting is the BIN number 1 to 100 in the SCORE column.
Say there are 300 records in my data frame, the if I BIN the records into 100 BINs each BIN will have 3 records.

Actual Output:

```
RAW_SCORE   SCORE
0.000742    1
0.000745    1
0.000826    1
0.000849    2
0.000853    2
0.000884    2
0.000911    3
0.00097     3
0.001014    3
0.001027    4
0.001031    4
0.001042    4
.......
```

What is wrong? and How do I fix it?

Comment: Please share an example data frame in copy/pastable mode that people can work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your code is that you passed a sequence of bin intervals in the `pd.cut()` function. In this case, the cut will assign each of the `RAW_SCORE` values a bin amongst `{(1,2], (2,3],...,(99, 100]}`. Since all the `RAW_SCORE` values are <1, they do not belong to any bin and hence a `NaN` value.
In case you wanted 100 bins of uniform width, you could try:

```
df_output['SCORE'] = pd.cut(df_output['RAW_SCORE'], 100)
```

For just acquiring the bin ids, pass the parameter `labels = False` in the `pd.cut()` function. For example,

```
 df_output['SCORE'] = pd.cut(df_output['RAW_SCORE'], 100, labels = False)
```

and finally, transform the labels from the 0-99 range to 1-100 range by:

```
df_output['SCORE'] += 1
```

Comment: The actual output for SCORE column has to be BIN number 1 to 100

Comment: I'm assuming you need the bin label from 1-100 for each RAW_SCORE entry, where each bin has a uniform width.
In this case, you could pass the parameter labels = False in the pd.cut() function. This would give you a set of labels from 0-99. You can transform this labelling to 1-100 by assing 1 using df['bins'] = df['bins'] + 1

Answer (score 1):

@Aniruddha's answer might be what you are looking for in terms of output (but it is unclear), but since the lower bound value of the range is more than the values in the 'RAW_SCORE' column, that why you are getting NaNs. If you change 1 to 0 in the range, then the code will not return NaN values.

```
import pandas as pd
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'RAW_SCORE' : [.000742, .000745, .000826]})
bins = list(range(0, 101))
df_output['SCORE'] = pd.cut(df_output['RAW_SCORE'], bins=bins)
bins
```

Output:

```
    RAW_SCORE   SCORE
0   0.000742    (0, 1]
1   0.000745    (0, 1]
2   0.000826    (0, 1]
```

Comment: The actual output for SCORE column has to be BIN number 1 to 100

Comment: You have put your current output in a table. Can you put your expected output in a table in the question @Ram?